# log4j errors go to INFO.log

Tags: log4j

i have a log4j.xml and a scala file. I use slf4j.

this is the xml file

```xml
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="error" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/config-server/config-server-error.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="error"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="info" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/config-server/config-server-info.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="debug" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/config-server/config-server-debug.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <priority value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
    <appender-ref ref="debug"/>
</root>
```

but when I log an error as

```java
logger.error("Error")
```

that error goes to error.log file. But it also goes to info.log file. can someone help me to get this thing correct.

Answer (score 1):

I use this following configuration and able to see the log messages in separate log files

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="error" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="logs/config-server/config-server-error.log"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="error"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="info" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="logs/config-server/config-server-info.log"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="debug" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="logs/config-server/config-server-debug.log"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value="debug"/>    
    </root>
    <logger name="debug">
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="debug" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="info">
        <level value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="info" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="error">
        <level value="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="error" />
    </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

This is how I am using the logger

```java
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class TestLogger {
    private static Logger debugLog = Logger.getLogger("debug");
    private static Logger infoLog = Logger.getLogger("info");
    private static Logger errorLog = Logger.getLogger("error");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        debugLog.debug("Debug message");
        infoLog.info("Info message");
        errorLog.error("Error message");        
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work for me. it says this error.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (hms.config.server.Main$).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: just edit my earlier answer, Please check with latest.

Comment: that works for me :) . can you tell me a way to log all the error and info logs into debug.log file.

Comment: If you want to consolidate your logs in a file create an another appender and provide the reference of that appender to root logger. root logger will print all the log messages logged by another appenders.